# Symfony 4: Service shown as private when loaded from additional services yaml during being marked as public

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony4

I have Symfony 4 project.

And here is the service. It is marked as public and it is in separate cooperation.yml which is connected to project:

```
services:
    App\Matcher\CooperationSiteConfigMatcher:
        public: true
```

Here is class itself

```
<?php

namespace App\Matcher;

use App\Factory\CooperationOptionsFactory;
use App\Options\Cooperation\CooperationOptions;
use App\Resolver\SiteResolver;
use App\Factory\Exception\MissingCooperationOptionsException;
use Assert\AssertionFailedException;

class CooperationSiteConfigMatcher
{
    const TYPE_PARTNERSHIP = 'partnership';
    const TYPE_FRANCHISE   = 'franchise';
    /**
     * @var CooperationOptionsFactory
     */
    private $optionsFactory;
    /**
     * @var SiteResolver
     */
    private $siteResolver;

    /**
     * CooperationSiteConfigMatcher constructor.
     * @param CooperationOptionsFactory $optionsFactory
     * @param SiteResolver $siteResolver
     */
    public function __construct(CooperationOptionsFactory $optionsFactory, SiteResolver $siteResolver)
    {
        $this->optionsFactory = $optionsFactory;
        $this->siteResolver = $siteResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param $group
     * @return CooperationOptions
     * @throws AssertionFailedException
     * @throws MissingCooperationOptionsException
     */
    public function matchOptionsByGroupAndSite($group)
    {
        $domainAliasKey = $this->siteResolver->resolve();

        return $this->optionsFactory->createForSite($group, $domainAliasKey);
    }
}
```

Global service.yml base configuration:

```
 services:
        # default configuration for services in *this* file
        _defaults:
            autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
            autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
            public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                                # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                                # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
    App\:
        resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/*'
        exclude: '%kernel.root_dir%/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Form/EventListener,Request}'
```

But I receive an error:

> The "App\Matcher\CooperationSiteConfigMatcher" service or alias has
>   been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should
>   either make it public or stop using the container directly and use
>   dependency injection instead.

The problem disappears when I move this service to global services.yml.

My custom services.yml is loaded via CooperationExtension class:

```
class CooperationExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $config = $this->processConfiguration(new CooperationConfiguration(), $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/services')
        );
        $loader->load('cooperation.yaml');

        $this->generateCooperationServices($config, $container);
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'cooperation';
    }

    public function getXsdValidationBasePath()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getNamespace()
    {
        return "cooperation/schema";
    }
}
```

Extension registered in Kernel.php configureContainer method:

```
 protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $cooperationExtension = new CooperationExtension();
        $container->registerExtension($cooperationExtension);
        $container->loadFromExtension($cooperationExtension->getAlias());

        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        // Feel free to remove the "container.autowiring.strict_mode" parameter
        // if you are using symfony/dependency-injection 4.0+ as it's the default behavior
        $container->setParameter('container.autowiring.strict_mode', true);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }
```

Symfony sees cooperation.yml. I checked it when removed some other services from it and exception appeared.

But somehow it do not merge it correctly with global services.yml and I don't see this service as public when load it from cooperation.yml

Comment: Can you show controller code, where you want to use that service?

Comment: @Zorpen, added controller part

Comment: You really should use DI instead like `public function cooperation($group, Request $request, CooperationSiteConfigMatcher $configMatcher)`

Comment: I'm not talking only about this case. What if don't want always use DI? The question is why is it not working. Is it correct behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you checked the namespace of your service? And could you show us some more detailes of your `service.yaml`?

Comment: Do you use multiple files for configuring your services? If so, could you explain the structure a bit? It could be that when loading the configs your change is overwritten by another one, e.g. when a whole directory is loaded like in the services.yaml with `App\`. Are there any other definitions specific to your service or to multiple resources (like App\) inside this file? If so, please update the service definition snippet to show them and their ordering.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Service with problem is not in global services.yml, but when I move it here - nothing changes. Still same problem

Comment: Well actually it works from global services.yml and do not work from my custom services.yml, that is loaded from custom extension registered in Kernel

Comment: Are you specifically excluding the src\App\Matcher directory in your app/config/service.yml?  I think the service is getting processed twice.  Once in your extension and once by your main service file.  Update your question with the App\: section of app/config/services.yml if you have one.

Comment: I have it. Actually, current question is that services added not through global services.yaml, but through cooperation.yaml which is loaded in custom extension, that is added in Kernel.php method configureContainer ($container->registerExtension(new CooperationExtension()) are not in container. And how to achieve it

Comment: So why is CooperationSiteConfigMatcher not excluded?  Is Cooperation a different bundle?  If not then why do you need a configuration for it?  Hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  If all you need is to load cooperation.yml then a simple import will take care of it.

Comment: Can you show me example of what you mean by importing cooperation.yml?

Comment: Here is an example of [importing service files](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/config/services.yaml) distributed over a project.  It is a bundle-less app organized somewhat differently than a typical Symfony app.  Notice that there is no global "turn everything under src into a service" line.